# Parse Json Data in Structure format in ASP.Net (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

[image: My code screenshot]

I just want the JSON data to be return in a particular format like one array above all the details. Please go through the picture which has the code and the output which i want to achieve.

```
 public IEnumerable <Data> Get()
    {
        return new List<Data> {
           new Data {Id=1,Content="Sample Content",Author="Bhanu"},
           new Data {Id=2,Content="Sample Content",Author="War"}
        };

    }
```

The above code in written in Controllers.cs and the data is getting from model class which has the ID,Content,Author declaration like below code.

```
namespace WebApplication1.model
{
    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set;}
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: i even written the code in text. For better output visualization i added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model class with a property of type IEnumerable like this:

```
public class DataModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Data> Something {get; set; }
}
```

Then return an instance of above mentioned class:

```
 public DataModel Get()
    {
        return new DataModel { Something = new List<Data> {
           new Data {Id=1,Content="Sample Content",Author="Bhanu"},
           new Data {Id=2,Content="Sample Content",Author="War"}
        }
     };

    }
```